# Hide the javascript innerHTML after error is corrected

Tags: javascript

I have used the following javascript code to add inline error in my form. I want to error to be removed after the error is corrected after each field is corrected. I have created a single function for all the validations, so not able to use else and remove the error manually.

```js
var emailpattern = /^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*(\.[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*\.([a-zA-Z]{2,4})$/

var passwordpattern = /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[$@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*?&]{8,}$/;

function validateForm() {
  var x = document.forms["LoginForm"]["email"];
  if (x.value == "") {
    x.value = "";
    document.getElementById('pointemail').innerHTML = "Please enter the email id.";
    x.focus();
    return false;
  } else if (!emailpattern.test(x.value)) {
    x.value = "";
    document.getElementById('pointemail').innerHTML = "Please enter a valid email address.";
    x.focus();
    return false;
  }
  x = document.forms["LoginForm"]["password"];
  if (x.value == "") {
    x.value = "";
    document.getElementById('pointpassword').innerHTML = "Please enter the password.";
    x.focus();
    return false;
  } else if (!passwordpattern.test(x.value)) {
    x.value = "";
    document.getElementById('pointpassword').innerHTML = "Password should have minimum 8 characters, one upper case, one lower case and one special character";
    x.focus();
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Just add an `else` block at the end for valid state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
var emailpattern = /^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*(\.[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*\.([a-zA-Z]{2,4})$/

var passwordpattern = /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[$@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*?&]{8,}$/;

function validateForm() {
  var x = document.forms["LoginForm"]["email"];
  document.getElementById('pointemail').innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById('pointpassword').innerHTML = "";

 //Add your if else here.
}
```

Hope it will be useful. :)

Comment: It will be useful if you dont want to use else. It will first blank and after that check.

Comment: you are running it by the change event?

Answer (score 0):

Provide an extra else statement after elseif

```
else {
  document.getElementById('pointemail').innerHTML = '';
}
```

Similarly for `pointPassword`